# fgetcsv convert array to string with double quote enclosure

Tags: php, arrays, csv, fgetcsv

I am getting data from a csv as an array using the `fgetcsv` function. I want to convert the array into a string, so I have used the `implode` function.

**CODE:**

```
if (($handle = fopen("storelocations.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
        $datafinal = implode(",",$data);
        echo $datafinal;
    }
    fclose($handle);
}
```

I am getting the result string say as `Ter Aar, Netherlands,4.7159509,52.164688,,211316`. ***But I would like each entry to be enclosed by double quotes. How can I do that?***

Expected result: `"Ter Aar", "Netherlands","4.7159509","52.164688","","211316"

**My approach #1 -**

I passed the `"` as enclosure following the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php) but it is not working.

```
if (($handle = fopen("../storelocations.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",", '"')) !== FALSE) {
        $datafinal = implode(",",$data);
        echo $datafinal;
    }
    fclose($handle);
}
```

**My approach #2 -**

```
function convert( $str ) {
   return '"'.$str.'"';
}

if (($handle = fopen("../storelocations.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",", '"')) !== FALSE) {
        //$datafinal = array_map( convert, $data );  
        $datafinal = implode(",",$data);
        echo $datafinal;
        //var_dump($data);
    }
    fclose($handle);
}
```

This returns a string as `"Ter Aar", "Netherlands","4.7159509","52.164688","","""211316"`.

As you can see the item following the blank data gets three quotes in the beginning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it as follows

```
// PHP 5.3 and later
echo $datafinal = implode(",",array_filter($data, function($value) { return $value !== ''; }));
```

This will help you sure

Thanks
Hope! It will help you

Answer (score 1):

Try following code to read csv file and get data as multi-dimentional array

```
$csv_data = array_map('str_getcsv', file('../storelocations.csv'));
foreach ($csv_data as $key => $value) 
{
    var_dump($value); // print each row of csv
    var_dump($value[0]) // print first column of each row
}
```